# footer mozzilla html5

Tags: css, html, firefox, footer

The footer looks further down in Mozzilla Firefox 14.0.1 while in Safari and Chrome looks fine.
It works fine in all browsers, but it is a lot different in terms of look, like 20 or 30px further down (in Firefox).

What to do to make them look the most similar as possible?

HTML:

```
<footer>
  <a href="mailto:info@site.com ?subject=Hello">Contact us</a>
  <p id="copy">&copy 2012<?php echo date('Y'); ?> someone.</p>
</footer><!-- #footer -->
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    width: 740px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 23px;
    background: #222222;
    position: relative;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    color: #cf2e45;
}
```

Comment: I assume it is an element above your footer. Try replicating on JSFiddle and share your Fiddle here.

Comment: I now have been playing around with the wrapper and seems i found a fair solution giving to it an height of about 650px.

Comment: If there's a specific browser issue you run into, you can use a js module recognizing browsers so that you can target this specific browser in your CSS. You can use [this](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/) one for browser recognition.